# AES and SHA512 encryption/decription between C# and ruby

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, aes, sha

The process of encrypting and decrypting my code does not match the bank's process. That is, when I use my code to encrypt and decrypt everything works fine. But when I try to send the result of the encryption of my code to the bank, they answer me with an error 500, on the other hand, the decryption process with an example of the bank, shows special characters at the beginning of the result.

I based my ruby code in this [C# code](https://estradawebgroup.com/Post/Cifrar-y-descifrar-contrasenas-o-cadenas-de-texto-en-C-/20363)

My code:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

class SecurityManager
  PASSWORD = 'example'.freeze
  CERT_PATH = Rails.root.join('config', 'documents', 'EXAMPLE_EMPRESA.pfx').to_s.freeze

  def self.encrypt(plain_text)
    return nil if plain_text.nil?

    bytes_to_be_encrypted = plain_text.encode('UTF-8')
    aux = get_thumbprint_from_certificate

    key = aux + PASSWORD
    password_bytes = key.encode('UTF-8')

    password_bytes = OpenSSL::Digest.new('SHA512').digest(password_bytes)

    bytes_encrypted = encrypt_internal(bytes_to_be_encrypted, password_bytes)

    Base64.strict_encode64(bytes_encrypted)
  end

  def self.decrypt(encrypted_text)
    return nil if encrypted_text.nil?

    bytes_to_be_decrypted = Base64.strict_decode64(encrypted_text)

    thumbprint = get_thumbprint_from_certificate
    key = thumbprint + PASSWORD
    password_bytes = key.encode('UTF-8')

    password_bytes = OpenSSL::Digest.new('SHA512').digest(password_bytes)

    bytes_decrypted = decrypt_internal(bytes_to_be_decrypted, password_bytes)

    bytes_decrypted.force_encoding('UTF-8')
  end

  def self.encrypt_internal(bytes_to_be_encrypted, password_bytes)
    salt_bytes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].pack('C*')

    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
    cipher.encrypt

    key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac(password_bytes, salt_bytes, 1000, cipher.key_len, 'sha1')

    cipher.key = key[0, 32]
    cipher.iv = key[0, 16]

    cipher.update(bytes_to_be_encrypted) + cipher.final
  end

  def self.decrypt_internal(bytes_to_be_decrypted, password_bytes)
    salt_bytes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].pack('C*')

    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
    cipher.decrypt

    key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac(password_bytes, salt_bytes, 1000, cipher.key_len, 'sha1')

    cipher.key = key[0, 32]
    cipher.iv = key[0, 16]

    cipher.update(bytes_to_be_decrypted) + cipher.final
  end

  def self.thumbprint_from_certificate
    pfx_data = File.read(CERT_PATH)
    pfx = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(pfx_data, PASSWORD)
    cert = pfx.certificate
    OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new(cert.to_der).hexdigest
  end
end
```

Encrypted example:

```
MRehs7Hr5+hN5ug8fhpsIrmlXgqChPAs82lYUvIw1gVhSM56MjlWSk5JNP3UvqKsJw1Grb6C2Q5pKqvyKPiq2W8cr0ZAQBS2aqP0RSD/D4m2ID4oxZix4b5ZljPd2899
```

Result of my code

```
"\xBF\xF2\xF1\xC9}\xBC\xBF\x91U\xF9nn\f\xFA\xF6\xA8essage\":\"Los datos personales del usuario son incorrectas.\",\"body\":null}"
```

Expected result

```
"{\"message\":\"Los datos personales del usuario son incorrectas.\",\"body\":null}"
```

Other result from another encrypted example of the bank:

```
"\xBFݒ\x9A\u0012\xF7\xBD\x89P\xF7om\b\xB8\xAD\x8Cd\": 2295,\r\n    \"password\": \"example\",\r\n    \"documentNumber\": \"XXXXXXX\",\r\n    \"documentType\": \"Q\",\r\n    \"documentExtension\": \"LP\",\r\n    \"documentComplement\": \"\",\r\n    \"amount\": 0.3,\r\n    \"currency\": \"BOL\",\r\n    \"fundSource\": \"Ventas de tarjetas de regalo\",\r\n    \"fundDestination\": \"Comercios que realizaron las ventas\",\r\n    \"sourceAccount\": \"2011040905323\",\r\n    \"sourceCurrency\": \"BOL\",\r\n    \"description\": \"Pagos por ventas efectuadas\",\r\n    \"sendVouchers\": \"info@example.com\",\r\n    \"cismartApprovers\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"idc\": \"04011574-Q-PO\",\r\n            \"type\": 1\r\n        }\r\n    ],\r\n    \"spreadsheet\": {\r\n        \"formProvidersPayments\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"paymentType\": \"PROV\",\r\n                \"line\": 1,\r\n                \"accountNumber\": \"2011040905323\",\r\n                \"glossPayment\": \"Pago por ventas\",\r\n                \"amount\": 0.1,\r\n                \"documentType\": \"Q\",\r\n                \"documentNumber\": \"0280000\",\r\n                \"documentExtension\": \"\",\r\n                \"firstDetail\": \"detalle 1\",\r\n                \"secondDetail\": \"detalle 2\",\r\n                \"mail\": \"\"\r\n            }\r\n        ],\r\n        \"formAchPayments\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"paymentType\": \"ACH\",\r\n                \"line\": 1,\r\n                \"accountNumber\": \"5555555555\",\r\n                \"titularName\": \"nombre de titular\",\r\n                \"firstLastName\": \"\",\r\n                \"secondLastName\": \"\",\r\n                \"amount\": 0.2,\r\n                \"branchOfficeId\": 201,\r\n                \"firstDetail\": \"detalle\",\r\n                \"mail\": \"\",\r\n                \"bankId\": \"8888\"\r\n            }\r\n        ],\r\n        \"formOddPayments\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"paymentType\": \"ODD\",\r\n                \"line\": 1,\r\n                \"accountNumber\": \"cuentaAdebitar\",\r\n                \"titularName\": \"William\",\r\n                \"firstLastName\": \"Prueba\",\r\n                \"secondLastName\": \"Prueba\",\r\n                \"description\": \"pruebaDescripcion\",\r\n                \"glossPayment\": \"pruebaGlosa\",\r\n                \"amount\": 0.3,\r\n                \"documentType\": \"Q\",\r\n                \"documentNumber\": \"7894561\",\r\n                \"DocumentExtension\": \"LP\",\r\n                \"branchOfficeId\": 201,\r\n                \"firstDetail\": \"DET ODD\",\r\n                \"SecondDetail\": \"SEC ODD\",\r\n                \"mail\": \"example@examplecom\",\r\n                \"bankId\": \"8888\",\r\n                \"commission\": 0.1,\r\n                \"CommissionCurrency\": \"BOL\"\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }\r\n}"
```

As you can see, the special characters are only at the beginning.

Comment: Is it possible there's a CRLF to LF encoding issue here, or vice-versa?

Comment: Uhmm the document has CRLF encoding  but the utf-8 endoding doesn't standardize it?

Comment: I'm more concerned with what happens to the encoded output. If any of those bytes are altered you have problems decoding. This could happen during reading or writing if, say, UTF-8 encoding is used for the encrypted output, where that should be strictly "BINARY" at least until you safely Base64 encode it, or however you're treating it here.

Comment: UTF-8 can mangle bytes, and so can CRLF conversions, so be sure that it's byte-for-byte identical to what it should be.

Comment: My mind just exploded. Any advice on how to check or test what you mention?

Comment: It is curious that the first 16 bytes of your output are trashed, but then it's fine. Usually I see it go the other way, from fine to trashed as the state gets messed up during decoding. It's also weird that those 16 bytes represent the first 3 bytes of what should be there: `{"m`

Comment: The IV is determined incorrectly. In the C# code, the first 32 bytes of the KDF are the key and the **following** 16 bytes are the IV (so the KDF must return 48 bytes). A wrong IV results in a corrupted first block (16 bytes) for AES/CBC.

Comment: Thus apply `cipher.key_len + cipher.iv_len` as 4th param in `pbkdf2_hmac()` and as IV `cipher.iv = key[32, 16]`.

Comment: I applied the corrections as follows:

TypeError (wrong argument type Integer (expected OpenSSL/Digest)) for the 4th param. And  ArgumentError (iv must be 16 bytes) for `cipher.iv = key[32, 16]`

Comment: Solved!!! Thanks I'll update the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

And a special mention to [topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) for his analysis.

Corrected code:

```
def self.decrypt_internal(bytes_to_be_decrypted, password_bytes)
    salt_bytes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].pack('C*')

    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
    cipher.decrypt

    key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac(password_bytes, salt_bytes, 1000, cipher.key_len + cipher.iv_len, 'sha1')

    cipher.key = key[0, 32]
    cipher.iv = key[32, 16]

    cipher.update(bytes_to_be_decrypted) + cipher.final
  end
```

And the encryption would look like this:

```
def self.encrypt_internal(bytes_to_be_encrypted, password_bytes)
    salt_bytes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].pack('C*')

    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
    cipher.encrypt

    key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac(password_bytes, salt_bytes, 1000, cipher.key_len + cipher.iv_len, 'sha1')

    cipher.key = key[0, 32]
    cipher.iv = key[32, 16]

    cipher.update(bytes_to_be_encrypted) + cipher.final
  end
```